# Is it possible to use all your features through another character?

Tags: dnd-5e

I recall having read a post (or watched a video) in which someone described a build which allowed a DnD5e character to stay at home all the time while still using their features through another character. If I remember correctly, the build used a specific warlock invocation.

I am now trying to find how to execute this build and I have looked through all warlock invocations + subclasses but cannot find the build.

Does anyone know if it is possible to design a character that does not need to leave their bed while functioning effectively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mention of a Warlock Invocation sounds like the build might have used the  One DND Player's Handbook Playtest version of the Warlock Invocation "Gaze of Two Minds."

From the Unearthed Arcana [UA2023-PH-Playtest5.pdf](https://media.dndbeyond.com/compendium-images/one-dnd/ph-playtest5/owThVp1CESZ1c91y/UA-2023-PH-Playtest5.pdf?icid_source=house-ads&icid_medium=crosspromo&icid_campaign=playtest5), Page 36:

> GAZE  OF  TWO MINDS
>
> Prerequisite: 5th-level   Warlock or  Higher
>
> You   can use a   Bonus   Action to   touch   a   willing
> Humanoid  and perceive    through its senses  until the   end of  your    next    turn.   As  long    as  the creature is on  the same    plane   of  existence   as  you,    you can use a   Bonus   Action  on  subsequent  turns   to   maintain   this    connection, extending   the duration until  the end of  your    next    turn.
>
> While perceiving  through the other   creature’s  senses, you benefit from    any special senses  possessed   by  that    creature,   **and   you can cast spells as  if  you were    in  your    space   or  the other    creature’s space.**

(Emphasis to show one of the major differences between the Unearthed Arcana playtest and 5e version)

Notably, this does not allow the use of *all* character features while staying at home, merely spellcasting,  and uses up the Warlock's Bonus Action constantly while it is going on, but it could be the reason why you attribute that capability to a Warlock build.

Comment: Uneathed Arcanas are always playtest material and never considered official material.

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, with *Magic Jar*

Warlocks with the Genie patron (from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, p. 73) have an expanded spell list that is adding *wish* as a 9th spell level option to your available spells (accessible through the Mystic Arcanum feature).

Wish will allow you to cast *magic jar*. Magic jar in turn will allow you to possess another creature, and use all your class features while doing so and while your own body stays back at home in bed.

> Once you possess a creature's body, you control it. Your game statistics are replaced by the statistics of the creature, though you retain your alignment and your Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores. **You retain the benefit of your own class features.**

Note that this does not protect you from dying, because

> If the host body dies while you're in it, the creature dies, and you must make a Charisma saving throw against your own spellcasting DC. On a success, you return to the container if it is within 100 feet of you. Otherwise, you die.

(*Magic Jar* works for any other classes that can use it too, of course. For example a wizard could cast it naturally at level 11, as it it part of the standard wizard spell list, a bard could get it with Magical Secrets at level 14, etc. I focused on Warlock, because the question seems most interested in that).